# Optimizing Very Large Distance Matrix Processing Workflow

Tags: python, matrix

I'm working with extremely large distance matrices produced by clustal omega application that's involved in some bioinformatics pipeline I'm developing , and I'm stuck with the following issue :

The distance matrices processing is repeating it self at a certain point of time , in which the element represented by an index of a column corresponding to some row index occurs twice in each file ,  e.g. : position row(1)-column(2) equals to (21.944035) which exactly the same value as in position row(2)-column(1) , and so on .

If I managed to avoid repeating the processing workflow twice for every element in the file , I can enhance the speed of my script and decrease the memory requirements needed to store the results .

This is a very tiny sample of one of my 9725 x 9725 space delimited distance matrices , and you can see how elements match for every unique position - With No Respect To Order - of indices .

```
100.000000 21.944035 22.133939 23.723042 19.750284 20.431328 20.885358 21.679909
21.944035 100.000000 22.827688 21.796760 22.974963 20.324006 21.944035 24.889543
22.133939 22.827688 100.000000 21.152030 22.474032 17.387033 19.830028 20.963173
23.723042 21.796760 21.152030 100.000000 20.437018 24.361493 19.059107 19.436957
19.750284 22.974963 22.474032 20.437018 100.000000 21.414538 20.094259 21.765210
20.431328 20.324006 17.387033 24.361493 21.414538 100.000000 20.432220 20.432220
20.885358 21.944035 19.830028 19.059107 20.094259 20.432220 100.000000 19.018898
21.679909 24.889543 20.963173 19.436957 21.765210 20.432220 19.018898 100.000000
```

Here's the script snippet I wrote with python to avoid the diagonal wise values as they represent an index against itself :

```
for i in range(len(files)):
    name=files[i][files[i].find("-")+1:files[i].find(".")]
    retrieved=open("Rtrv-"+name+".csv",'w',newline='')
    retrieved.write(str('{0:^14}\t{1:^8}\t{2:^10}\n'.format(str("Similarity (%)"),str("Query ID"),str("Subject ID"))))
    data=np.genfromtxt(files[i])
    for row_idx, row in enumerate(data):
        for col_idx, element in enumerate(row):
            if row_idx==col_idx :
                continue
            elif ("Left" in name and element>=90.000000):
                retrieved.write(str('{0:10.6f}\t{1:0d}\t{2:0d}\n'.format(element,row_idx,col_idx)))
            elif ("Right" in name and (100-element)>=50.000000) :
                retrieved.write(str('{0:10.6f}\t{1:0d}\t{2:0d}\n'.format(element,row_idx,col_idx)))
    retrieved.close()
```

**My question is :** How can I alter my code to avoid the reprocessing of the same position appears later in the file ?!

Comment: Do you just want to process values above the diagonal (not the diagonal itself, and nothing below because it's just reflected) or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: @NickT ... I'm not really sure whether it's a mirror reflection matrix as it's very large sized and I couldn't catch it's boundaries to decide that :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop skips the diagonal.

```
for row_idx, row in enumerate(data):
    for col_idx, element in enumerate(row):
        if row_idx == col_idx:
            continue
```

This minor tweak skips the diagonal and everything below (`==` → `>=`)

```
for row_idx, row in enumerate(data):
    for col_idx, element in enumerate(row):
        if row_idx >= col_idx:
            continue
```

If you don't know for sure if the matrix is symmetric, you could add a check:

```
for row_idx, row in enumerate(data):
    for col_idx, element in enumerate(row):
        if row_idx >= col_idx and data[row_idx][col_idx] == data[col_idx][row_idx]:
            continue
```

Comment: So that tiny little symbol can do the Job !!! things get obvious when someone pointed them out , I will try that thanks a lot :)

Comment: That minor tweak `row_idx<=col_idx` will skip diagonal and **everything above** , and `data[row_idx][col_idx] == data[col_idx][row_idx]` will return an **empty file** , would you please correct that in your answer ?! Thanks a lot .

Comment: @Bara'a I flipped the inequality, but not sure what you mean by the empty file...is the indexing wrong, e.g. should it be `data[row_idx, col_idx]`?

Comment: @NickT...no the indexing is correct , I meant : that condition will skip the diagonal and everything above , beside any two identical values which leaves the output file empty !!

Comment: @bara if it fails one side of the `and`,  it will skip the if statement that skips processing (with `continue`). It would have to be on one side of the diagonal (whichever doesn't matter presumably),  AND the value would have to equal it's mirror... Or am I reading the logic wrong?

Comment: @bara did you put all your logic into that if statement instead of using it as a skip?

Comment: @NickT...you're absolutely right , I got confused by the `continue`  statement and I need it to be written that way to skip half of the work and reduce the memory  requirements .